# How can I get Python to read a list from a .txt document for my Discord bot

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, discord.py

````
wordfilter = ["badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword"]```
````

```
@client.listen('on_message')
async def msgfilter(message, member: discord.Member = None):
    global messageserver
    messageserver += 1

    for word in wordfilter:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Is my code but I recently updated the filter to match derogative use of words in every language for my Discord bot. It has over 10000+ lines in a list like this:

`wordfilter = ["badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword"]`

but for thousands or words from 105+ languages. I have tried to put this into my main python file as it is a custom bot for my server and I want members not be able to bypass the filter in anyway possible. Once I copied the list into a the same file python file, it crashed and makes the py document unresponsive and slow to save. It works well in a txt file but how can I get the python file to get the same achievement from accessing the words from another file and filtering the way I have done it. Please let me know soon! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is inefficient because you iterate on your list of badwords, and for each iteration again on the message (for `count`), which makes it O(length of words list * length of message).

You should use sets: a set of your badwords

```
wordfilter = {"badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword", "badword"}
```

and a set of the word in your message:

```
words = set(message.content.split())
```

Testing if the message contains a bad word is then just:

```
if not words.isdisjoint(wordfilter):
    # there is a badword in your message
```

which will be much more efficient.

Another option would be to test if any word of the message is part of the set, with:

```
words = message.content.split()
if any(word in wordfilter for word in words):
    # there is a badword in your message
```

Testing if an item is in a set is just O(1), and this would stop as soon as a bad word is found.

You should test and compare.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample.txt**

```
badword1
badword2
badword3
...
badwordn
```

**Python Code:**

```
with open("Sample.txt","r") as f:
    bad_words=f.readlines()
print("length of all bad words are ",len(bad_words))
```

Comment: can I have the txt document with the list I already have? Instead of creating lines for each word?

Comment: @Cohen yes, simply have to write the elements of a list in a .txt file using python